# Compile 32 bit at&t assembly program on 64 bit linux not working

Tags: gcc, ld, gnu-assembler

Trying to compile a 32 bit asm program with the following commands.

```
 as --32 select.s -o main.o
 ld -m elf_i386 -I/lib/ld-linux.so.2 -lc main.o -o main
```

Outputs:

```
In function _start':
(.text+0x21): undefined reference to esp'
```

Using the following gcc command:

```
gcc -m32 -nostartfiles -o main select.s -v
```

Outputs:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.9.2-10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i586 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-m32' '-nostartfiles' '-o' 'main' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 as -v --32 -o /tmp/ccGkw2Rn.o select.s
GNU assembler version 2.25 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.25
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib32/:/lib/../lib32/:/usr/lib/../lib32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-m32' '-nostartfiles' '-o' 'main' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc1n81fB.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o main -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/32 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib32 -L/lib/../lib32 -L/usr/lib/../lib32 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../.. /tmp/ccGkw2Rn.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed
/tmp/ccGkw2Rn.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `esp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using 64 bit debian jessie. Surely, there is some way to compile 32 bit asm programs on 64 bit machines? Preferably with gas and ld. A gcc command would also be helpful.I got these commands from other stackoverflow posts that were also having trouble compiling 32 bit assembly programs on 64 bit machines. I must be missing something... Please help. Thank you.

Comment: It might be helpful to include the actual asm you are trying to assemble (at least enough to illustrate the problem).  Depending on the assembler, it may be necessary to prefix register names with a % sign (ie `%esp`).

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the comment to an 'answer' (since apparently I guessed correctly):

Depending on the assembler, it may be necessary to prefix register names with a % sign (ie `%esp`).